# corner rounder videoview kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, video, android-videoview

hi i'm new to android and i don't know how i could make my video look like this.

Could you guide me on how to make the video like the image? [image_video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oj8td.png)

Thanks for the help

I have echo a shape and I use it from background in my xml but it doesn't work

this is in me shape

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="90dp"
        android:topRightRadius="90dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
        />

    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:centerColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:type="linear" />

    <padding
        android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp"
        />
    <size
        android:width="270dp"
        android:height="400dp"
        />
</shape>
```

but the result is the following

[image_video_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03KMQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a workaround but could work for you:

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="680dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="140dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp">
    <VideoView
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp" />
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Note that the card height is video height + cornerRadius * 2